# apply template in LibreOffice Writer to existing document

Tags: libreoffice

is there a way to apply a template to an existing document?

It only seems to work when I create a completely new document, and i don't want to copy&paste everything.

Answer (score 6):

I'm searching for the same solution. The only thing I've found is a LibreOffice extension to do it. I just tested it and it worked, only I had to add the .oxt extension after downloading it.

[Template Changer](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/template-changer)

p.s. As this was not a programming question, it may not be appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution without installing an extension:

Create a new document in the desired template.

From the menu, choose Insert -> Text from file ... and select the document you would like to transfer to the new template.

Then the old document appears in the new template.

Comment: Best solution, just don't forget to "save as..." the edited template

Comment: In my current version of Libreoffice this option is called "Document", hence from the menu choose Insert -> Document.

Comment: I have tried this solution. When inserting the file, it also inserts the styles from the old document.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from LaTechneuse no longer seems to apply (2020-08-09, v. 5.4.4.2). There is no such option under "Insert"...

However there is an option Insert --> Document. This seems to do the same thing. No doubt the menu command's name was  changed because it was felt that LibreOffice users were having it too easy. Never waste an opportunity to confuse people needlessly and cause them to waste their time.

Answer (score 0):

Neither template changer worked nor could I find one of the options that should reside in Insert->...

However, I used manage templates to import the new template and then in the presentation to change, in the sidebar the master slide view.
And it worked!